# issue on switching to new domain

Tags: wordpress

I have two active HostGator hosting accounts. one is single domain and hosting and another is multi-domain hosting. each is in separate accounts.

I have two domain on GoDaddy. one domain which is lumakkreads. com  being used with single hosting service(being used for last 6 month). The another domain of lumakk.com is connected to multi-domain hosting service(not in use).

today I transferred all the files from single domain hosting to multi-domain hosting. Now when I enter the lumakk.com it getting redirected to lumakkreads.com. I am confused how could I solve this issue. The website is wordpress website, if any other information need let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're transfering a `wordpress` site to another domain you should also be sure that you've changed your `site url` to your new domain. You're able to check if your `site url` is set right by changing it through the `/wp-admin` area. go to:

Admin => Settings => Wordpress site_url

Do also check, if you do have a .htaccess file, if there maybe a rerouting function set.

Comment: Firstly sorry for late reply and secondly thanks for a kind reply. I have changed the site URL and admin in SQL file through PHP admin, then it worked fine. But now all the web page are taking a long time to load. Each and every page taking so long to load. Could you help in identifying where the issue is